# Reorder event on frontend

Tags: magento2, event-observer, reorder

I need to observe when the user is reordering an order (to delete a product), but i can't find the event, which one is it ?

Comment: there is no special event for the reorder button

Comment: So what controller should I override ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to work on `Magento\Sales\Controller\AbstractController\Reorder:: execute()` controller Action.

As `execute()` as **public** method you use **plugin** instead of  class rewrite.

```
<?php


namespace StackExchange\Magento\Plugin\Magento\Sales\Controller\AbstractController;

use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class Reorder {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface
     */
    private $messageManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart
     */
    private $cart;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory
     */
    private $resultRedirectFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Controller\AbstractController\OrderLoaderInterface
     */
    private $orderLoader;

    /**
     * @var Registry
     */
    private $registry;

    public function __construct(
      \Magento\Sales\Controller\AbstractController\OrderLoaderInterface  $orderLoader,
      \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory $resultRedirectFactory,
      \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart, 
       \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,  
       Registry $registry     
    ) {

        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->orderLoader = $orderLoader;
        $this->resultRedirectFactory = $resultRedirectFactory;
        $this->cart = $cart;
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
    }
    public function aroundExecute(
     \Magento\Sales\Controller\AbstractController\Reorder $subject 
    ){
      $result = $this->orderLoader->load($subject->getRequest());
        if ($result instanceof \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface) {
            return $result;
        }
        $order = $this->registry->registry('current_order');
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $cart = $this->cart;
        $items = $order->getItemsCollection();
        foreach ($items as $item) {

            try{
               $cart->addOrderItem($item) ;
            }catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {  
                if ($this->cart->getUseNotice(true)) {
                    $this->messageManager->addNoticeMessage($e->getMessage());
                } else {
                    $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
                }
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/history');
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage(
                    $e,
                    __('We can\'t add this item to your shopping cart right now.')
                );
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('checkout/cart');
            }
        }

        $cart->save();
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('checkout/cart');
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I use the plugin ?

Comment: @Morgan for more info on plugins https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

Comment: Thanks ! I'll take a look`